# How to create Package.Dependency.package from the content of the json file?

Tags: ios, swift, dependencies, swift-package-manager

My swift package has an external dependencies which have defined in a JSON file dependencies.json, and it is in a same directory as package.swift file,

```
[
    {
        "name":"Package1",
        "url": "https://github.com/xxxx/Package1",
        "version": "1.0.0"
    }
]
```

Now in a package.swift I want to read the file, parse it and want to append the package.dependencies,

```
struct Dependency: Decodable {
    let name: String
    let url: String
    let version: String
}

func addDependencies() {
    let dependencies = getDependencies()
    for dependency in dependencies {
        let packageDependency = Package.Dependency.package(url: dependency.url,
                                                           exact:  Version(stringLiteral: dependency.version))
        package.dependencies.append(packageDependency)
    }
}

func getDependencies() -> [Dependency] {
    let fileName = "dependencies.json"
    let fileURL  = fileURL how to get it?

    guard let jsonData = try? Data(contentsOf: fileURL) else {
        fatalError("Failed to load JSON data \(fileURL) and directory \(currentDirectoryPath)")
    }
    
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    
    guard let dependencies = try? decoder.decode([Dependency].self, from: jsonData) else {
        return []
    }
    return dependencies
}
```

I am not sure how to get the path of the dependencies.json file. I don't think  `Bundle.main.url(forResource: "dependencies", withExtension: "json")` will work here.